# Compare data google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am using google sheets and I want to compare the quantity of interactions o a given person in a period of time.

My problem is that between one week and another, the people can change, some people can have no interactions and is not reported and I can have new people.

So I need a formula that allow me to compare the previous period of time but also the name.

I am trying this in order to follow up how the people's behavior is changing.

This is the [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RVWRZyyQRfSGuj-OzijYhn6SNLeWzOg1tY-Gl5kIwiU/edit?usp=sharing).

Thanks

Comment: If you are just looking to determine the difference between two cells, just subtract them.  `=cell1-cell2`.

Comment: This is a pretty open-ended question - why not show us how you would do it manually. If the image above is a sample of the raw data, how about showing how you want the result to appear. Maybe provide a link to a Google spreadsheet (because no-one can scrape the sample data off an image). Help us to help you.

Comment: When you say "compare the quantity"... do you mean to compare with the next day or with the previous day? A worked manual example really would be a big help. BTW, how many entries per day? Is it just the four names as shown here, or are the more or fewer, and how many?

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy, quick-and-dirty solution using vlookup.
There are two variations. One using a single criteria and one using multiple criteria. infoinspired.com has a good article on [How to Use VLOOKUP with Multiple Criteria in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-in-google-sheets/).

**Single Criteria**: This is the formula.

```
=iferror(vlookup((B2+1)&C2,$A$2:$D$9,4,false),"error")
```

[image]
This involves a cheat by creating a new column A which contains the concatenation of the date and name values for each row. This is a unique value.

The lookup criteria is the (date (B2) plus 1=the next day) and the name.
The lookup range is self-explanatory and the value returned is the Quantity (from column 4).
The vlookup formula is inside an iferror() so that any problems are highlighted.

**Multiple Criteria**: This uses an array formula.

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup((B2+1)&C2, {B2:B&C2:C, D2:D}, 2, 0 ), "error"))
```

[image]
The vlookup component is very similar to the "simple" formula. The difference is that each criteria 1:(Date plus 1) and 2:Name are recognised separately, and assigned discrete lookup columns (B and C respectively).
Again, the whole thing is wrapped in an iferror statement to highlight any problems.

This [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IijKoRSRqvDkTgbZjdqFcRlrx30qsHKYw9MYuMI78pM/edit?usp=sharing) shows the workings: